# Scaffold Create and Edit Views with Dropdownlist in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, scaffolding

I have a MVC3 application  that populates a dropdownlist from a Model. When I select an item from the list , i would like to Update the url  `('/Edit/4')` on a single 'edit' link  which will allow me display the edit view, i.e rather than use a template which creates edit links for all records in the model, I would like to use one edit link and then update  it as items are selected in the dropdownlist. I have been able to achieve some of this using jquery , I would like to do it in C# code using MVC.

Any thoughts??

Comment: DropDownlist or selectlistbox ?

Comment: I created an instance of `SelectList` and then used it in the `DropDownList`

Comment: You mean you have a dropdownlist and a link. on selecting the item in ddl, and clicking the link will navigate the user to edit page which will have url ends with `/Edit/4`

Comment: exactly ! That's what I would like to accomplish

Answer (score 3):

I created a Sample code. I have an area. Highlighted part is your concerned code.

[image]

### **Controller**

```
public class DropdownController : Controller
{
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult DropDownListFor()
    {
        Practise.Areas.MyPractise.Models.Dropdown d = new Models.Dropdown();
        return View(d);
    }

    public ActionResult Edit(string Val)
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

### **Model**

```
public class Dropdown
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please select state")]
    public string StateId { get; set; }
    public int MyProperty { get; set; }
    public List<SelectListItem> States
    {
        get
        {
            return new List<SelectListItem>() 
                { 
                    new SelectListItem
                    { 
                        Text = "Punjab", 
                        Value = "Pb", 
                        Selected = false
                    },
                    new SelectListItem
                    { 
                        Selected = false, 
                        Value = "HM", 
                        Text = "Himachal"
                    }
                };
        }
    }

}
```

### **DropDownListFor View**

```
@model Practise.Areas.MyPractise.Models.Dropdown
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>DropDownListFor</title>
    <script src="/Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#StateId').change(function () {
            if($('#StateId option:selected').val() == "")
                $('.edit').attr('href', "#");
            else
                $('.edit').attr('href', 
                    "@Url.Action("Edit", "Dropdown", 
                       new RouteValueDictionary(new { area = "MyPractise" }))" 
                           + "/" + $('#StateId option:selected').text());
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
        @using (Html.BeginForm("DropDownListFor", "DropDown", FormMethod.Post, 
                                 new { id = "DropDownList" }))
        {
            @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.StateId, Model.States, "select");
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.StateId);
            <a class="edit" href="#">Edit</a>
            <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit" />
        }
</body>
</html>
```

### **Area registration under MyPractiseAreaRegistration class under highlighted area**

```
public class MyPractiseAreaRegistration : AreaRegistration
{
    public override string AreaName
    {
        get
        {
            return "MyPractise";
        }
    }

    public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context)
    {
        context.MapRoute(
            "MyPractise_default1",
            "MyPractise/{controller}/{action}/{Val}",
            new { action = "Index", Val = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );

        context.MapRoute(
            "MyPractise_default",
            "MyPractise/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            new { action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```